# Extjs 4 - combine 2 layouts

Tags: layout, extjs4, extjs

I am using Extjs 4 and I need to combine between card and border layout on one panel. card to create a wizard and border to create a child panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `combine` layouts - you `nest` them. Basically you would create something like this:

```
{
  xtype: 'panel',
  layout: 'card',
  items: [{  
    xtype: 'panel',
    layout: 'border'
  }, {
    xtype: 'panel',
    layout: whatever... 
  }]
}
```